# Discord.py Dropdown Interaction Fails to Respond

Tags: python, postgresql, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a Discord.py bot using version 3.14. My goal is to create a command called showdecks that displays a dropdown menu of available decks and, upon selection, fetches and displays the names of the cards in the chosen deck.

```
class MyDropdownView(View):
    def __init__(self, decks):
        super().__init__(timeout=60)
        self.decks = decks
        self.add_item(discord.ui.Select(
            placeholder="Choose a Deck ...",
            options=self.decks,
            custom_id="deck_selection"
        ))

    async def on_select(self, interaction, choice):
        if choice.component.custom_id == "deck_selection":
            selected_deck_id = choice.values[0]
            # Retrieve card names from the database based on the selected_deck_id
            card_names = retrieve_cards_for_deck(selected_deck_id)

            # Create a string with card names
            card_names_string = "\n".join(card_names)

            # Create an embed with card names
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Deck Cards", description=card_names_string, color=discord.Color.blue())

            await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=False)

@bot.command()
async def showdecks(ctx):
    # Retrieve deck information from the database
    decks = retrieve_decks()

    if not decks:
        await ctx.send("No decks found.")
        return

    # Convert decks to a list of SelectOption
    deck_options = [discord.SelectOption(label=deck['name'], value=deck['id']) for deck in decks]

    # Create a dropdown menu view with deck options
    view = MyDropdownView(deck_options)

    await ctx.send("Choose a deck to view:", view=view)
```

**What did i try:**
I have attempted to create a Discord.py bot with version 3.14 that includes a command named showdecks. This command is intended to provide users with a dropdown menu of available decks. When a user selects a deck from the dropdown, the bot should fetch and display the names of the cards within that chosen deck.

To accomplish this, I have implemented the following code:

I created a custom view named MyDropdownView that extends discord.ui.View to handle the dropdown interaction.
Within MyDropdownView, I implemented the on_select method to respond when a deck is selected. This method retrieves card names based on the selected deck and creates an embed with the card names.
I used the discord.ui.Select component to create the dropdown menu, populated it with deck options, and assigned it a custom ID.
**What were you expecting:**
I expected that when a user runs the showdecks command, a message with the text "Choose a deck to view:" and a dropdown menu containing the available decks would be displayed in the Discord channel. Upon selecting a deck from the dropdown, I anticipated that the bot would respond with an embed containing the names of the cards within the chosen deck.

However, the issue I encountered is that the interaction with the dropdown menu fails to respond. After selecting a deck, the bot does not display the card names, and no response is provided in the channel.

I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue to ensure that the dropdown interaction works as expected, displaying the card names when a deck is selected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to relate your `on_select` function to the callback of your `Select` component. You can do this explicitly by providing the `callback` parameter to the `discord.ui.Select` class, or use the `@discord.ui.select()` decorator to create your `Select` normally and then edit the options (easier). Look:

```py
class MyDropdownView(View):
    def __init__(self, decks):
        super().__init__(timeout=60)

        # self.children is a list with all components 
        # attached to the view
        select = self.children[0]

        # edit the options of your select created bellow
        select.options = decks

    @discord.ui.select(placeholder="Choose a Deck ...", custom_id="deck_selection")
    async def on_select(self, interaction, choice):
        selected_deck_id = choice.values[0]
        # Retrieve card names from the database based on the selected_deck_id
        card_names = retrieve_cards_for_deck(selected_deck_id)

        # Create a string with card names
        card_names_string = "\n".join(card_names)

        # Create an embed with card names
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Deck Cards", description=card_names_string, color=discord.Color.blue())

        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=False)

@bot.command()
async def showdecks(ctx):
    # Retrieve deck information from the database
    decks = retrieve_decks()

    if not decks:
        await ctx.send("No decks found.")
        return

    # Convert decks to a list of SelectOption
    deck_options = [discord.SelectOption(label=deck['name'], value=deck['id']) for deck in decks]

    # Create a dropdown menu view with deck options
    view = MyDropdownView(deck_options)

    await ctx.send("Choose a deck to view:", view=view)
```